# How to send json to rest service to make Jersey to parse it as a POJO?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jersey, jax-rs

This is my code that makes ajax call using jquery:

```
$.get("/login", { token: { name:"Donald", password:"Ducktown" }} , 
     function (data) {
            console.log(data);
 });
```

This is my POJO:

```
public class Token {

    private String name;

    private String password;

    public Token() {}

    //+getters, setters, toString
}
```

This is my rest service:

```
@Path("login")
public class LoginService {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginService.class);

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void login(Token token) {
        logger.info("Token={}", token);
    }
}
```

And this is output:

```
12:16:12.211 [qtp967677821-35] [INFO] com.foo.LoginService - Token=null
```

Please, say how to send json correctly to make Jersey to parse it as a POJO.

This is jersey config info, that is printed in logs when Jersey starts:

> Root Resource Classes:   com.foo.LoginService
>
> Pre-match Filters:
> org.apache.shiro.web.jaxrs.SubjectPrincipalRequestFilter
>
> Global Response Filters:    com.foo.CORSFilter
>
> Global Reader Interceptors:
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor
>
> Global Writer Interceptors:
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor
>
> Dynamic Features:
> org.apache.shiro.web.jaxrs.ShiroAnnotationFilterFeature@204beb58
>
> Message Body Readers:
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SaxSourceReader
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FormProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$DomSourceReader
> org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FormMultivaluedMapProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ByteArrayProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.BasicTypesMessageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider
>
> Message Body Writers:
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.RenderedImageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FormProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedResponseWriter
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter
> org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FormMultivaluedMapProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ByteArrayProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.BasicTypesMessageProvider
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider

And these are my dependencies for Jersey. As gson parser I try to use jackson:

```
    <module groupId="jakarta.validation" artifactId="jakarta.validation-api" version="2.0.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.sun.activation" artifactId="jakarta.activation" version="1.2.1"/>
    <module groupId="jakarta.ws.rs" artifactId="jakarta.ws.rs-api" version="2.1.6"/>
    <module groupId="jakarta.xml.bind" artifactId="jakarta.xml.bind-api" version="2.3.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.google.code.gson" artifactId="gson" version="2.8.6"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml" artifactId="classmate" version="1.5.1"/>
    <module groupId="com.sun.xml.bind" artifactId="jaxb-impl" version="2.3.2"/>
    <module groupId="javax.enterprise" artifactId="cdi-api" version="1.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.hk2.external" artifactId="jakarta.inject" version="2.6.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.hk2" artifactId="hk2-api" version="2.6.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.hk2" artifactId="hk2-utils" version="2.6.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.hk2" artifactId="hk2-locator" version="2.6.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.hk2" artifactId="spring-bridge" version="2.6.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.containers" artifactId="jersey-container-jetty-http" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.containers" artifactId="jersey-container-servlet-core" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.core" artifactId="jersey-server" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.core" artifactId="jersey-common" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.core" artifactId="jersey-client" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" artifactId="jersey-bean-validation" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi" artifactId="jersey-cdi1x" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi" artifactId="jersey-cdi1x-servlet" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.inject" artifactId="jersey-hk2" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" artifactId="jersey-spring5" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="com.sun.istack" artifactId="istack-commons-runtime" version="4.0.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.javassist" artifactId="javassist" version="3.27.0-GA"/>

    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" artifactId="jersey-entity-filtering" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="org.glassfish.jersey.media" artifactId="jersey-media-json-jackson" version="2.30.1"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" artifactId="jackson-annotations" version="2.10.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" artifactId="jackson-core" version="2.10.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" artifactId="jackson-databind" version="2.10.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.module" artifactId="jackson-module-jaxb-annotations" version="2.10.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs" artifactId="jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" version="2.10.2"/>
    <module groupId="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs" artifactId="jackson-jaxrs-base" version="2.10.2"/>
```

**EDIT 1**
When I change get to post (in javascript and in login service) I get:

```
13:41:00.345 [qtp967677821-38] [WARN] org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent - A servlet request to the URI http://127.0.0.1:8080/login contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
13:41:00.359 [qtp967677821-38] [TRACE] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder - Starting mapping of the exception.
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.getMethodRouter(MethodSelectingRouter.java:412) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.access$000(MethodSelectingRouter.java:73) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter$4.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:665) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:305) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173) ~[jersey-common-2.30.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245) ~[jersey-server-2.30.1.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have, it should work with this:

```
$.get("/login", {name:"Donald", password:"Ducktown"} , 
     function (data) {
            console.log(data);
 });
```

Your POJO mapping has the fields `name, password`, so your JSON should only contain them:

```
ublic class Token {

    private String name;

    private String password;

    public Token() {}

    //+getters, setters, toString
}
```

---

When you send in `{ token: { name:"Donald", password:"Ducktown" }}`, you are stating your Pojo should look like:

```
public class TokenWrapper {

    private Token token;
}


public class Token {

    private String name;

    private String password;

}
```

And your API endpoint should change to:

```
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void login(TokenWrapper token) {
        logger.info("Token={}", token);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried `$.get("/login", {name:"Donald", password:"Ducktown"},...) but result is the same: Token=null. Does your solution work with jersey?

Comment: You probably dont have the proper dependencies then, that automatically take the JSON and map it into a POJO.  Please see https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/#jersey-endpoints-and-return-a-json-response and also show your dependencies if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added all the information in the question.

Comment: Please change it to post instead of get

Comment: I changed. Please, see my edit 1.